Как узнать дату установки системы Fedora Linux?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне узнать дату установки системы Fedora Linux?
Спасибо.

sudo rpm -qi basesystem
Смотрите на строку вида
Install Date: Friday 23 April 2021 04:27:31 PM

Огромное спасибо, нашел дату установки

а при обновлении не обновится?

Эквивалентом даты установки системы можно принять дату создания корня системы
stat -c'%w' /

